# psycopg2 and mod_python import error

Tags: apache, mod-python, psycopg2

I am trying to setup [roundup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/roundup) on a windows XP machine.
I use psycopg2 v2.0.13 and when i import the psycopg2 module from the shell it all works fine, but when mod_python tries to do it, I get this error:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      3464
Interpreter:    'roundup'

ServerName:     'roundup'
DocumentRoot:   'C:/Dev/roundup/tracker'

URI:            '/index.html/'
Location:       None
Directory:      'C:/Dev/roundup/tracker/'
Filename:       'C:/Dev/roundup/tracker/dummy.py'
PathInfo:       '/index.html/'

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'roundup.cgi.apache'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\mod_python\importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\roundup\cgi\apache.py", line 107, in handler
    _tracker = roundup.instance.open(_home, optimize=0)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\roundup\instance.py", line 300, in open
    return Tracker(tracker_home, optimize=optimize)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\roundup\instance.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.backend = backends.get_backend(self.get_backend_name())

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\roundup\backends\__init__.py", line 46, in get_backend
    module = __import__(module_name, vars)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\roundup\backends\back_postgresql.py", line 18, in <module>
    from psycopg2 import psycopg1 as psycopg

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from _psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the Visual Studio Redist: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=766a6af7-ec73-40ff-b072-9112bab119c2

Choose the one that conforms better to your system.